# break in for loop

Tags: language-agnostic, for-loop, control-structure

Assume you have this code:

```
function doSomething($array)
{
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)
  {
    if ($array[$i] == "ok")
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Note that I'm not talking about PHP specific (this applies to all languages) or this particular example. It's about breaking in the for loop (in this case, return true; stops the loop).

According to a teacher of me, this is very, very bad and a not-done practice.

Is breaking from a loop really a not-done practice?

Thanks

Comment: Did your teacher supply any reasons for his statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to break or return from a loop.

What your teacher possibly refers to is the classic *a function should have only one return point* extended to loops. The rationale behind this is, that your control flow should always be as easy and understandable as possible. It's not a strict rule that you have to obey without thinking.

To rewrite your sample without using `break` and `return`:

```
function doSomething($array)
{
  $ret = false;
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array) && !$ret; $i++)
  {
    if ($array[$i] == "ok")
      $ret = true;
  }

  return $ret;
}
```

That's painful to read and maintain. Yours is mich more concise.

Comment: Of course, there is also the opposite doctrine for functions: the rule of breaking (returning) early. It means the main flow of your code will not be very indented and, thus, easy to follow and all the conditions that violate your main flow are stacked together at the top.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The teacher was not talking about returning at multiple points as she said "never use break other than in switch-statements". She also talked about multiple return points, however, she didn't make a big problem of that, while she talked about breaking in loops as one of the worst things ever.

Comment: That's rubbish. Write code that is easy to read and maintain. Keep the control flow as straightforward as possible.

If you're *done with the job that you started the loop for*, `break` it. If you're done with the entire function (including cleanup), `return` from it. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stay away from breaks in loops if possible. If your loop gets bigger it becomes increasingly hard to read. Anyone not familiar with your code or that specific function will assume that your loop iterates over the whole array just by looking at the first line. To do anything else is "surprising" and thus breaks the "Principle of Least Astonishment" from the CleanCode philosophy. If you've got multiple conditions to exit your loop, then a for-loop isn't the one you should be looking for. That's what while-loops are for.

```
function doSomething($array) {
    $found = false;
    $i = 0;

    while ($i < sizeof($array) && !$found) {
        if ($array[$i] == "ok") {
            $found = true;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $found;
}
```

Comment: In certain situations a `while` is surely the best solution. But if you can use a simple `foreach` with a single break condition inside, `break` does not sound something unreadable...

Comment: There are two kinds of loops (short ones, like the one above and complex ones). With loops as short and inexpensive as the above a while-loop is over the top by some degree, as is a break. Just use foreach and be done with it. With complex (and more expensive) loops comes the argument of readability. A loop with one or several breaks in if or else clauses scattered through the code is hard to read and should be avoided what's where a while-loop comes in.

Comment: A more complex loop is not certain to be an expensive one either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be a bad practice. These types of things, like breaking a loop, or using a return in the loop are just things that should not be done carelessly.

When I was a beginner, I always heard these things. Don't use this, or don't use that. But later I realized they only say this to keep newcomers from committing bad mistakes by using these things carelessly. And people who don't realize this, and later become teachers themselves, will keep you away from these as they were something evil.

So yes, use it, it is very very handy sometimes. Just note all the things you have to care about when using these, as others here have mentioned. Learn when you should not use them.

(**One more thing:** getting the array's dimension in the loop's condition is considered bad practice indeed. You don't want to get the size on every iteration.

Instead of:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)
```

Use:

```
$size=sizeof($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
```

)

Answer (score 1):

Some program design approaces like [Jackson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_Structured_Programming) are not really friends with breaking loops. This is a rather academical argument and not really followed in real life.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing bad about breaking in loops. It is like a very limited goto. Do not care about your teacher :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bad practice to break a loop. However, I usually do it by using either `break` or `continue`, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

People usually say that using `break` or `continue` (or their equivalents) is bad.  I use them anyway :-P

Another way to do it is to wrap all code in an `if` or an `else`.

```
function doSomething($array)
{
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)
  {
    if ($array[$i] != "ok"){
       // do stuff...
    }
    else{
      // do something else
      // or omit this else block to do nothing
    }
  }
}
```

In the case of `return`ing from a loop.  I suggest you set a variable outside the loop, break the loop when needed, then return the variable.

```
$ret = false;
function doSomething($array)
{
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++)
  {
    if ($array[$i] == "ok"){
      $ret = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return $ret;
}
```